# Datatype of currency with ","

Tags: powerbi

I am having trouble setting the datatype for a currency column with value `6.670.000,00`. I have tried setting the datatype as decimal and also as currency, but both datatypes are showing an error when I close apply query.

[image]

Comment: Try using 667.000,000; maybe your code throws errors when you input it with the periods and comma in the wrong place. **Please show us your code.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the locale settings, since some countries use only "," or only "." as a decimal symbol or separator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/supported-languages-countries-regions